# How can I install my Canon PIXMA MP210?

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon

I could install it on 11.04 by selecting MP220 Driver, but on 11.10 y can't select drivers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Here (at the bottom of the page) you'll find the driver. Just download, unrar and click on the .deb file:

[MP210 print driver](http://www.canon.es/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/MP210.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:86-738151&page=1&type=download)

Hope this help.

Comment: the link no longer works

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with the MP220 driver selected from the driver list :)

1. Search "printe" on unity dash or go to "system settings" and select "Printing"
2. Select add new printer and select to add the recognized MP210
3. it now begins to search for driver, cancel it.
4. Select driver from list.
5. Select Canon
6. Find and select MP220 printer
7. install the printer with it by going forward.
8. Printing should now work :)

Tested today on ubuntu 11.10 and printed just fine, scanning has worked always for me.